# Is it possible to customise a javascript function name using Model data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In javascript, I know I can get a value from my model into a javascript variable as follows:

```
function myFunctionName() 
{
    var id = @Model.ID;
    //etc
}
```

What I'd like to do is customise the name of the function itself using the Model ID value, so that it comes out like:

```
function myFunctionName_1() 
{       
   //etc
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, if I understand you correctly. You can do it like this:

```
function myFunctionName_@(Model.ID)() 
{       
   //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the name of the function at **runtime** but you can create an **alias** function (using your model data) and use that instead.

FYI, the [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) may also be of interest to you which is basically another way to refer to function itself.